# How to default logic high after a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider, pullup

I have a 5V logic pin coming in that I want to cut down to 3.3V.  When the 5V pin is detached, however, I want the pin to default logic high (3.3V).  How can I choose R_pu appropriately?

V_in = 5V
VCC 3.3V
R1 = 20k
R2 = 33k
Rpu = ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no universal answer, since the strength of the pullup depends on the current from the high voltage side. That's why a diode translator is more effective:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWYS7T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A low on the input pulls the output down to V<sub>f</sub>. A high on the input 
is blocked by the diode, and the pullup pulls it up to 3.3V. And since there is a pullup, a floating input lets it take over to pull the output up.

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio gives you an excellent solution.  There is also another method: resistive voltage divider to ground plus a pullup-up resistor to +5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqAO3x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has the advantage of having symmetrical rise & fall times if you add a noise-suppression capacitor to the 3.3V node.

There is one other advantage of a purely-resistive divider: if the input of the diode-coupled level translator shown above should ever have a significant transient that goes below ground, the diode will happily couple that transient directly into the 3.3V logic input.  That doesn't happen with the resistive divider shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Both are good solutions. For bidirectional lines it is common to use a levelshifter circuit.[image]